# f(R) action and GYH term

Tags: general-relativity, variational-principle, modified-gravity, boundary-terms

I have the following question. I have done integration by parts and I'm now applying the Gauss-Stokes theorem to get the boundary terms. I'm not interested in ignoring the terms, rather keeping them and varying the GYH term in the action to cancel them. I'm specifically interested in these 2 definitions and how to proceed:

$$U^\sigma |_{\partial V}=-F(R)g^{\sigma\mu}g^{\nu\gamma}\delta g_{\mu\nu,\gamma}\qquad V_{\tau}|_{\partial V}=-F(R)g^{\kappa\lambda}\delta g_{\kappa\lambda,\tau}$$

where $F(R)=\partial f(R)/\partial R$. Defining the inverse transverse metric as $h^{\alpha\beta}=g^{\alpha\beta}-\epsilon n^\alpha n^\beta=e^{\alpha}{}_a e^\beta{}_bh^{ab}$, where $h^{ab}$ the inverse induced metric, $\epsilon=n^\mu n_{\mu}=\pm 1$ and $n_\mu h^{\mu\gamma}=n_\mu e^\mu{}_m e^\gamma{}_c h^{mc}=0$, we have that for example:

$$n_\sigma U^\sigma|_{\partial V}=-F(R)n_\sigma(h^{\sigma\mu}+\epsilon n^\sigma n^\mu)(h^{\nu\gamma}+\epsilon n^\nu n^\gamma)\delta g_{\mu\nu,\gamma}\\
=-F(R)n^\mu(h^{\nu\gamma}+\epsilon n^\nu n^\gamma)\delta g_{\mu\nu,\gamma}$$

I cannot understand why the 3 $n$ term vanishes and I also have a problem with the definition that the tangential derivative is $e^{\gamma}{}_c\delta g_{\alpha\beta,\gamma}$. Could you provide a good definition of the tangential derivative as a map and an explanation why this should be set to 0 due to the variation of the metric vanishing at the boundary? Is it the analogous Neumann boundary condition?

Please be as thorough as possible.

P.S: reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0617.pdf
My question is particularly why equation 3.20 is valid. I understand the part with the tangential derivative of the variation that vanishes, but I do not grasp the fact that the $n^\mu n^\nu n^\gamma$ term vanishes too.

Comment: What "3 n term vanishes" ? What is the GYH term? Where are you reading from? Please be as thorough as possible.

Comment: The GYH term is the Gibbons-York-Hawking boundary term added to the Einstein Hilbert action (contains the extrinsic geometry when embedding the boundary). $n^\mu$ is the unit vector normal to the surface of the manifold.

Comment: Tip: Consider to add references and context to receive focused answers.

Comment: just got it. the normal vectors from both expressions simply cancel each other.